# I don't get the expected feedback of a basic rectangle collision implementation in C++

Tags: c++

I am building a basic game in which I have to detect collisions between an array of sprites. For now the sprites just move forward and change direction randomly or when reached a screen edge. The game is made in C++ with my college graphics library.

I implemented a basic algorithm for detecting collisions into this function:

```
    bool DetectarColisionTanques(strTanque tanque1, strTanque tanque2) {
    if( 
        (tanque1.px + tanque1.width >= tanque2.px) &&
        (tanque1.px <= tanque2.px + tanque2.width) &&
        (tanque1.py + tanque1.height >= tanque2.py) &&
        (tanque1.py <= tanque2.py + tanque2.height)
        ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Sorry that code is in Spanish, tanque1 and tanque2 are 2 structs containing each sprite coordinates which I want to see if collide, px and py are the sprite origin at the upper left edge of the image.

But when I try to run the function I don't get the expected feedback:

```
    void MoverEnemigos(){
    for (int i=0;i<nEnemigos;i++) {
        switch (enemigos[i].dir) {
            case 0: enemigos[i].py-=enemigos[i].vel;break;
            case 1: enemigos[i].px+=enemigos[i].vel;break;
            case 2: enemigos[i].py+=enemigos[i].vel;break;
            case 3: enemigos[i].px-=enemigos[i].vel;break;
        
        for (int k= i+1; k<nEnemigos; k++) {
            if(DetectarColisionTanques(enemigos[i],enemigos[k])) {
                printf("Collision detected");
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        
        }
        
        enemigos[i].width= esat::SpriteWidth(spriteTanque[enemigos[i].dir]);
        enemigos[i].height= esat::SpriteHeight(spriteTanque[enemigos[i].dir]);
    }
    
}
```

In this function called MoverEnemigos() I move all the sprites px and py depending on their direction and then I try to call the function DetectarColisionTanques() to see if I get the printf at the same time I see in my graphic window that the sprites are obviously colliding. But I never ever get the printf.

PD: All the functions are running in a while at 60fps.

Comment: Why have you got the for in scope of the switch?

Comment: It was that thank you!! Never mix functions again

Comment: px and py represent top left corner, correct?